# VBA Excel Instr() StrComp() not working properly

Tags: excel, vba, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two strings, however, the functions are returning bad matches. I tired using three different methods and posting the results for each method in different columns to test. I tired to compare using "string1" = "string2", instr(), and strcomp().

they dont even return the same results for each method when using the same two strings; sometimes one type of comparison is true and others may not be.

for false positives, Instr() returns a position, but substring is not in target string, Strcomp() returns 0 but the words are not the same, and "string1" = string2" is true but the strings are different.

```
Worksheets("hemo").Cells(f, 1) = Trim(Worksheets(Stabv).Cells(Count, 1))
Worksheets("hemo").Cells(f, 2) = Len(Trim(Worksheets(Stabv).Cells(Count, 1)))
Worksheets("hemo").Cells(f, 3) = Trim(LitBaseArray(y))
Worksheets("hemo").Cells(f, 4) = Len(Trim(LitBaseArray(y)))

scrapeString1 = Trim(Worksheets(Stabv).Cells(Count, 1))
scrapeString2 = Trim(LitBaseArray(y))

If scrapeString1 = scrapeString2 Then
Worksheets("hemo").Cells(f, 5) = "true"
End If

If StrComp(Trim(scrapeString1), Trim(scrapeString2), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
Worksheets("hemo").Cells(f, 6) = "true    " & StrComp(Trim(scrapeString1), Trim(scrapeString2), vbTextCompare)
End If

If InStr(1, Trim(scrapeString1), Trim(scrapeString2), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
Worksheets("hemo").Cells(f, 7) = "true    " & InStr(1, Trim(scrapeString1), Trim(scrapeString2), vbTextCompare)
End If

f = f + 1
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Check values of `scrapeString1` and `scrapeString2` while debugging.

Comment: Not the answer but you don't have to use `TRIM` again in `StrComp` and `InStr` as you are already assigning values to `scrapeString1` & `scrapeString1` using `Trim`.

Comment: yea, i was just trying different things out. i even tired to put the contents of the cell in a string.

Comment: Did you debug and check values of `scrapeString1` and `scrapeString2`?

Comment: I did. I need to sort out the values. There are more then 10k string comparisons. That's why I used a excel sheet instead of the debug window. It's easier to sort.

Comment: Put a break point in your code and debug using `F8` and check the values when you expect them to be same. See [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) for how to debug.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
If str1 = str2 Then
    'str1 is exactly similar with str2
    '"ABC" = "ABC", but "ABC" <> "Abc"
End If
```

2.

```
If StrComp(str1, str2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    'str1 is similar with str2, but in case insensitive manner
    'StrComp("ABC", "ABC", vbTextCompare) = 0 and
    'StrComp("ABC", "Abc", vbTextCompare) = 0 as well
    'Use binary comparison if you want similar behavior as for the = operator
End If
```

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx).

3.

```
If InStr(1, str1, str2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    'Will be true if str1 contains str2 in a case insensitive manner
    'To make it case-sensitive, use binary comparison instead of vbTextCompare
    'InStr(1, Nothing, "A", vbTextCompare) will be 0
    'InStr(1, "A", Nothing, vbTextCompare) will be 1 !
    'InStr(1, "", "A", vbTextCompare) will be 1 !
    'InStr(1, "ABC", "CD", vbTextCompare) will be 0
    'InStr(1, "ABC", "BC", vbTextCompare) > 0
    'InStr(1, "ABC", "AB", vbTextCompare) > 0
    'InStr(1, "ABC", "abc", vbTextCompare) > 0
    'InStr(1, "ABC", "c", vbTextCompare) > 0
End If
```

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx).

As you can see, different behavior can be expected in the different cases, especially since you `Trim` them in some cases and not `Trim` them in others.

Comment: I appreciate the work you put into this answer, but my your answer is not the issue. I am getting false positives for strings tht do not have the same characters i them

Comment: @Padawan I think my answer addressed the problem you described in your question and in your comment here. If you think that I am misunderstanding you, then you could help me by giving an exact example of input, the exact code being executed, the exact output and the exact explanation of why is that output not meeting your expectations. If you do that, then I believe I will have enough information about your problem to help you.